# Unable to open database file error when generating mbtiles

Tags: sqlite, mbtiles, tippecanoe

I am creating a docker image to run few tippecanoe to generate mbtiles pointing to  a specific folder where all the .json are.

It seems to work fine when running the script in my local but when I tried to work with the docker it populates me this error:

```
tippecanoe: layer.mbtiles: unable to open database file
```

I think is related to sqlite, but I have tired to load different version of tippecanoe and sqlite to the image but cannot figure out what is going on.

This is the installation process I am following for tippecanoe in the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/jskeates/docker-tippecanoe/blob/master/Dockerfile)

Answer (score 1):

When running the docker image, try using your own directory path

```
docker run -it --rm \
  -v /tiledata:/data \
  tippecanoe:latest \
  tippecanoe --output=/data/output.mbtiles /data/example.geojson
```

i.e. the

> /tiledata